# xquery: count number of characters and paragraphs in ancestor (div) node up until a certain point in where child node occurs

Tags: count, xquery, exist-db

Xquery newbie here again. I have the following xml:

```
<div type="section" n="1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <rs type="xyz">consectetur</rs> adipiscing <placeName ref="#PLACE1">elit</placeName>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<p>

<p>Duis aute irure <rs type="xyz">dolor</rs> in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt <rs type="place" ref="#PLACE2">mollit anim</rs> id est <rs type="xyz">laborum</rs>.<p>
</div>
```

I would like to create a unique ID for each "place" (rs type=place and placeName) based on its position within the text. To do this, I'd like to retrieve the following information for each place:

- paragraph number within the "div type=section" node
- character count from the beginning of the paragraph to the start of the child node (rs type=place or placeName).

Taking the above example, I'd expect these results:

`<placeName ref="#PLACE1">elit</placeName>`

- paragraph: 1
- character count: 51 ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ")

`<rs type="place" ref="#PLACE2">mollit anim</rs>`

- paragraph: 2
- character count: 186 ("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt ")

I must be missing something very simple, but I just can't figure out how to do this particular character count in xquery. I know preceding/following-sibling::text() will allow me to count until the previous/following node. Is there something like this to get to the beginning of the ancestor from a given node? Any help or direction would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `place` and `rs` elements will be children of the `p` element then you just can select the `preceding-sibling::node()`, `string-join` them and then compute the `string-length`; so in XQuery 3.1 with the arrow operator (I hope exist supports that):

```
(//placeName | //rs[@type = 'place'])
!
(ancestor::p[1]/(., preceding-sibling::p) => count() ||
 ' : '
 ||
 preceding-sibling::node() => string-join() => string-length()
)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BK/1

For the more complex case that your elements are descendants of the `p` I think the expression

```
(preceding::text() intersect ancestor::p[1]//text())  => string-join() => string-length()
```

gives the value you want (https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BK/4), I am not sure how well that performs.

If the arrow and the map operator are not supported or you prefer a FLOWR expression then

```
for $place in (//placeName | //rs[@type = 'place'])
return ($place/ancestor::p[1]/count((., preceding-sibling::p)) || ' : ' || string-length(string-join($place/preceding-sibling::node())))
```

for the simple child element case or

```
for $place in (//placeName | //rs[@type = 'place'])
return (
    $place/ancestor::p[1]/count((., preceding-sibling::p)) 
    || ' : ' || string-length(string-join($place/preceding-sibling::node()))
    || ' : ' || string-length(string-join($place/(preceding::text() intersect ancestor::p[1]//text())))
)
```

as the descendant case (well, a comparison of both approaches, the last subexpression should work for the descendant case). An alternative to intersect could the use of the `<<` operator: `string-length(string-join($place/ancestor::p[1]//text()[. << $place]))`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great! I can count on my placename and rs[type='place] elements being the children of the p element, but unfortunately, there could be an intermediary element, for example: <p>As soon as he arrived, he said: "<q> I'm here in <placeName>Madrid</placeName>"</q></p> (apologies for the edit! I didn't realize return would submit). That seems to throw a monkey wrench into things...

Comment: @MeganCytron, see the edit. And wait if someone else has another suggestion (or at least judges the performance of that attempt).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thank you so very much for the creative solution-- that turned out to be a lot trickier than I thought it would/should be, so I sure am extra glad I asked.I didn't realize intersect could be used in that way.